# MongoDB shell 4.0.3 Windows cannot connect to MongoDB replica set: SSLHandshakeFailed: QueryContextAttributes for connection info failed

Tags: windows, mongodb

In Windows 10, I'm not able to connect to MongoDB server with the following errors:

```
>mongo "mongodb+srv://xxx-dsvlb.mongodb.net/test" --username xxx --verbose

2018-11-01T11:34:19.273+0700 D -        [main] User Assertion: DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":This operation returned because the timeout period expired. C:\data\mci\6411135b04f345f6d01072b56250cba6\src\src\mongo/util/dns_query_windows-impl.h 254
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
2018-11-01T11:34:30.535+0700 D -        [main] User Assertion: DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":This operation returned because the timeout period expired. C:\data\mci\6411135b04f345f6d01072b56250cba6\src\src\mongo/util/dns_query_windows-impl.h 254
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb+srv://xxx-dsvlb.mongodb.net/test
2018-11-01T11:35:16.589+0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":This operation returned because the timeout period expired. C:\data\mci\6411135b04f345f6d01072b56250cba6\src\src\mongo/util/dns_query_windows-impl.h 254
2018-11-01T11:35:16.590+0700 D NETWORK  [js] creating new connection to:xxx-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017
2018-11-01T11:35:17.356+0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: SSLHandshakeFailed: QueryContextAttributes for connection info failed with-2146893055 C:\data\mci\6411135b04f345f6d01072b56250cba6\src\src\mongo/transport/session_asio.h 240
2018-11-01T11:35:17.357+0700 D NETWORK  [js] creating new connection to:xxx-shard-00-01-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017
2018-11-01T11:35:18.197+0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: SSLHandshakeFailed: QueryContextAttributes for connection info failed with-2146893055 C:\data\mci\6411135b04f345f6d01072b56250cba6\src\src\mongo/transport/session_asio.h 240
2018-11-01T11:35:18.198+0700 D NETWORK  [js] creating new connection to:xx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017
2018-11-01T11:35:19.017+0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: SSLHandshakeFailed: QueryContextAttributes for connection info failed with-2146893055 C:\data\mci\6411135b04f345f6d01072b56250cba6\src\src\mongo/transport/session_asio.h 240
2018-11-01T11:35:19.018+0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: InternalError: couldn't connect to server lakon-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: QueryContextAttributes for connection info failed with-2146893055 src\mongo\scripting\mozjs\mongo.cpp 756
2018-11-01T11:35:19.021+0700 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server lakon-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: QueryContextAttributes for connection info failed with-2146893055 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
2018-11-01T11:35:19.024+0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: Location12513: connect failed src\mongo\shell\shell_utils.cpp 343
2018-11-01T11:35:19.024+0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 4056565 limit: 0
2018-11-01T11:35:19.027+0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 421536 limit: 0
2018-11-01T11:35:19.027+0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 313504 limit: 0
2018-11-01T11:35:19.028+0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 131244 limit: 0
2018-11-01T11:35:19.029+0700 D -        [main] User Assertion: Location12513: connect failed src\mongo\scripting\mozjs\proxyscope.cpp 300
exception: connect failed
```

Using MongoDB shell 3.6.2 on Windows 10, I still cannot connect but **with a different error** (confusing, isn't it?):

```
>mongo "mongodb+srv://xxx-dsvlb.mongodb.net/test" --username xxx --password xxx
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb+srv://xxx-dsvlb.mongodb.net/test
MongoDB server version: 3.6.8
2018-11-01T11:01:52.923+0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

However, with Ubuntu 16.04 I can connect just fine to the exact same server:

```
⟫ mongo "mongodb+srv://xxx-dsvlb.mongodb.net/test" --username xxx --password xxx
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb+srv://xxx-dsvlb.mongodb.net/test
2018-11-01T04:27:02.536+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for lakon-shard-0/xxx-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017,xxx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017,xxx-shard-00-01-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017
2018-11-01T04:27:02.561+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to xxx-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017 (1 connections now open to xxx-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2018-11-01T04:27:02.562+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to xxx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017 (1 connections now open to xxx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2018-11-01T04:27:02.563+0000 I NETWORK  [js] changing hosts to xxx-shard-0/xxx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017,xxx-shard-00-01-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017,lakon-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017 from xxx-shard-0/xxx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017,xxx-shard-00-01-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017,xxx-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net.:27017
2018-11-01T04:27:02.570+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to xxx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to xxx-shard-00-00-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2018-11-01T04:27:02.573+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to xxx-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to xxx-shard-00-02-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("4a6488c7-7a22-44d4-977e-07eb09ef37f6") }
MongoDB server version: 3.6.8
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2018-11-01T04:27:02.588+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to xxx-shard-00-01-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to xxx-shard-00-01-dsvlb.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
        http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
MongoDB Enterprise xxx-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

A MongoDB Atlas support staff told me this is due to network connection on my part, but I'm sure that is **not** the root issue, because **I can connect to the server when using other client such as [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/)** using the same Windows 10 computer.

This issue happens ONLY when using MongoDB shell (both 3.6.2 and 4.0.3) in Windows 10.

It's probably a bug with MongoDB Shell and Windows 10 implementation?

Comment: Try the "mongodb://" url - the one with list of all rs members. dns_query_windows-impl.h  was added to support new ""mongodb+srv://" urls: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commits/r4.0.3/src/mongo/util/dns_query_windows-impl.h

Comment: Just tried connecting to MongoDB Atlas using `mongodb+srv` URI in Windows 10 via MongoDB shell v4.0.3 without any issue. As suggested by @AlexBlex, try connecting with the old v3.4 URI via mongo shell. Also 1) Did you install using the `msi` or `zip`? 2) What is the instance size of your Atlas cluster ? i.e. M0, M5, M10,etc.

Comment: Did you every solve this issue? It happens for me randomly

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late but here, I had this problem when my shell's version is 4.0.5 then I install 4.2.11, it solve this problem. I tried many things with different connection string syntax and it does not solve the problem and still stuck at SSLHandshake error, so I guess if version were same it might solve the problem(mine 4.0.5 and remote was 4.2.11) and go ahead with new version installation(though I still think it's not version problem but I don't know what is). This problem only happen while I was in shell, connecting from the client like NoSqlBooster or Spring seem to work fine. My Robo3T have a problem connecting but randomly, sometimes once sometimes multiple re-trying.